# Confused results on Change grandparent state created by Hooks from grandchild?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to change grandParent state from grandchild, I know I should pass down some method to the grandchild component, after I tried, the result is confused.

If I pass the method step by step like GrandParent ---> Parent ---> Child, the result is as expected.

So the question comes: why should this happens?

https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-grass-45ifs

I expect once click the each item added:

- add a red "+" behind the item(this UI change is just for example), and
- log the current state in console correctly, but the red "+" did not show, because it's not the current state ,but looks like prev state?.

**APPEND**:

just as @Antonio said, the solution may be:

- In **setTodos**, I can use the preTodos to update.
- like what I have tried, Just pass down the method step by step, but not as grandchild component, can also fix the problem.

And now, the most important is:

**why did the console have different result?**

Answer (score 1):

There's a mistake in updating Object element in Array state with usState hook.

```
const toggleStarred = text => {
  console.log("toggle: ", todos);
  setTodos((prevTodos) => prevTodos.map((todo) => {
    if (todo.text === text) return {...todo, isStarred: !todo.isStarred}
    return {...todo};
  }));
};
```

Here is [codepen](https://codesandbox.io/s/elastic-brook-yifhi).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but why the log in console is different?